# Visual Studio 2015 MonoGame: Cannot find Texture2DReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, visual-studio-2015, monogame

This line of code

```
backgroundImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Backgrounds/titleScreen");
```

Causes this error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll

Additional information: Error loading "Backgrounds\titleScreen". Cannot find ContentTypeReader Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Texture2DReader.
```

This code was all working perfectly before I tried to convert this from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015. Inside my Content folder is a Backgrounds folder which has titleScreen.png, so I know that the path is correct.

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling MonoGame.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with .xnb files which is in bin\content folder.
Also double check the path of the texture and name of the file(I mean case sensitive).
I also when deployed in xna visual studio,it was working fine..when deployed in monogame,it was throwing error,I was trying the file name as screen,where as filename was SCREEN.
Safest is try using XNB files.

Comment: What do you mean try with .xnb files? Do you mean try loading the texture       from a xnb file instead of a png file?